# Difference between “competitive analysis” and “competitiveness analysis”

Tags: meaning, difference

What is the difference between “**competitive** analysis” and “**competitiveness** analysis”?

I find “competitive analysis” is a common term.

> Competitive Analysis
>
> Definition: Identifying your competitors and evaluating their
>   strategies to determine their strengths and weaknesses relative to
>   those of your own product or service
>
> https://www.entrepreneur.com/encyclopedia/competitive-analysis
>
> Competitive analysis or competitive research is a field of strategic
>   research that specializes in the collection and review of information
>   about rival firms.
>
> https://www.impactbnd.com/blog/5-ways-to-perform-a-competitive-analysis-establish-your-presence

I cannot find a ready definition for “competitiveness analyst”. But it is also used in news.

> “Tucson Roberts of Tucson/Atlantic Consulting and Robert Ingram of
>   Common Sense Economic Development discussed their three-month
>   assessment of the region, including its aerospace-related strengths
>   and weaknesses, as well as a strategic **competitiveness analysis**.”
>
> https://www.register-herald.com/news/greenbrier-valley-region-certified-as-aeroready/article_50f70309-bc5f-5023-928c-9af6b6b90757.html
>
> “Further, it includes a relative **competitiveness analysis** of different
>   CAR-T cell therapy-based gene editing platforms, based on various
>   parameters, such as ease of system design, cost of technology, level
>   of toxicity and efficiency of technology.”
>
> https://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/car-t-therapies-market-2nd-edition-2019-2030-300928619.html

Comment: is *competitive* outward looking (what others are doing) and *competitiveness* more inward looking (how are you or your product doing in comparison)

Comment: Both seem to be jargon for the same thing.  To some extent I prefer the longer "competitiveness" since it seems to more accurately reflect what is being analyzed -- i.e. how well a particular product or service can *compete* with others in the same market.

Answer (score -1):

The difference lies in what is being competitive.
It's either the analysis itself that is competitive or the things that you are analysing.

In a **competitive analysis** you are doing something competitive, investigating potential competitors or rivals.

Competitiveness, on the other hand, is the measure of how competitive something is. So a **competitiveness analysis** takes a look at what competitive things are done.

If you work for Apple and you're looking into what Android is bringing out and how to react to that, competitive analysis.

If you look at people working for Apple and how they respond to what Android is doing, competitiveness analysis.